# Prob. 41, Chap. 1, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS 4th ed: $\lim\inf a_n \leq \lim \sup a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Here is Prob. 41, Chap. 1, in the book *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden and P.M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Show that $\lim\inf a_n \leq \lim\sup a_n$.

Here $\left( a_n \right)$ is of course a sequence of real numbers. Moreover,
$$
\lim\inf a_n := \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf \left\{ a_k \, | \,  k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n \right\} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n} a_k,
$$
and
$$
\lim\sup a_n := \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \left\{ a_k \, |\, k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n \right\} = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sup_{k\in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n} a_k,
$$
where the $\inf$ and the $\sup$ in each case is taken over the extended real number system.

My Attempt:

> For any natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $m < n$, we find that
> $$
> \inf_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq m} a_k \leq \inf_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n} a_k \leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n} a_k, 
> $$
> and aslo
> $$
> \inf_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n} a_k \leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n} a_k \leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq m} a_k.
> $$

> Thus for any natural numbers $n$ and $m$, we have
> $$
> \inf_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq m} a_k \leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n} a_k. 
> $$
> So for any natural number $m$, we have
> $$
> \inf_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq m} a_k \leq \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N} }  \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n}  a_k = \lim \sup a_n,
> $$
> which in turn implies that
> $$
> \lim \inf a_n = \sup_{m \in \mathbb{N} } \inf_{k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq m} a_k \leq \lim \sup a_n, 
> $$
> as required.

Is this proof correct and clear enough in each and every detail? Or, are there any issues with it?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Do you realize what $\liminf a_n$ and $\limsup a_n$ really mean in terms of the sequence $\{a_n\}$?  Those definitions you give for them in terms of nested sups and infs hide their actual importance: $\liminf a_n$  is the *smallest limit point* of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ and  $\limsup a_n$ is the *largest limit point* of the sequence $\{a_n\}$. I think the most important thing to do is prove those interpretations of $\liminf a_n$ and $\limsup a_n$, since (1) it explains why anyone cares about these concepts and (2) it makes the inequality in that exercise completely obvious.

Comment: The term "limit point" in my 1st comment is a "cluster point" in your book. It simply means "limit of some subsequence of $\{a_n\}$". I first learned measure theory from Royden's book (before he died and Fitzpatrick came on as a co-author for the 4th edition) and your post led me to open my copy of the book to see how $\liminf a_n$ and $\limsup a_n$ are defined. It's awful!! These concepts are described only by nested sups and infs without giving the actual *meaning* of anything. Only when I learned these are simply the biggest and smallest limit points did I understand how to work with them.